# How to save/restore terminal output

Tags: terminal

Some programs like vim/nano/nload has the ability to use the whole terminal to display its content and upon exiting, the previous terminal output is restored. How do they implement this restoring process?

Comment: `printf \\33\[\?1047h` prints the `xterm` *private mode* [escape sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) for switching to the alternate screen buffer *(which does not store a scrollback)* and `printf \\33\[\?1047l` swaps back.

Comment: @mikeserv How about that trap stty -g technique?

Comment: @RobertL - `stty` affects the [*`termios`*](https://blog.nelhage.com/2009/12/a-brief-introduction-to-termios-termios3-and-stty/) structure of the kernel-managed serial device. any changes made that way aren't directly related to what the user-space terminal program does. doing `stty -echo;printf \\33\[\?1047h` will still result in no output when you press keys - the terminal program *(like `xterm`)* is reading input from the [pt]ty device and writing it to the screen. it intercepts some escapes and performs certain functions, but not at the same level `stty` changes do.

Comment: @RobertL - none of that is meant to imply that `trap` and terminal escapes cannot be usefully combined, of course. they are very handy when paired, actually.

Comment: @mikeserv This may be an over-simplification on a different level, but I always thought that programs like vi (console) or the curses library would save the stty settings, then set raw mode and do all io direct to the tty, filtered through termcap style library (TERM variable), controlling the screen directly, and then restore the stty settings at exit.  In that sense, I think the character codes to switch buffers are interpreted by `xterm`'s emulation of the console.  In that way I thought the stty settings might apply as the questioner mentioned "use the whole terminal to display".kkk

Comment: @RobertL - oh yeah, they usually do. `ex` is spec'd for canonical input, and `vi` for raw-mode input. but they don't use shell traps - and they don't affect the terminal through `stty` - they maintain their own local copies of the global structures. and anyway, that stuff is *hard*. the canonical `vi` - as you can see well-documented [here](http://ex-vi.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ex-vi/ex-vi/ex_tty.c?view=markup), might use t[ci] libs, and might not, but will try to do the right thing always. in any case, they don't do it with escape codes - they're almost always ioctls.

Comment: @mikeserv   `vi` can send escape codes, via the ncurses library (libtinfo5).  I don't know what `ncurses` sends to an xterm.  So vi does this: save `termios` state (`stty -g`),  changes termios state to raw (`stty raw`),  uses `ncurses` routines, `tput` for example, to control the full screen display. When done, `vi` restores the termios to the default line input state (with the results of `stty -g`). `vi` doesn't use shell traps and commands, but calls the same underlying system calls as the shell and `stty`. The model is almost the identical.

Comment: @mikeserv Not sure what you mean by hard :-).  It's only hard until you know it.  To me the question is what do you want to know and how much of it?

Answer (score 10):

> How do they implement this restoring process?

They don't.  It's not theirs to implement.

This is the so-called *alternate screen buffer* being switched in and out.  It's implemented in the terminal (or terminal emulator program) itself.  The terminal responds to control sequences that are emitted by such TUI programs.  The TUI programs control *when* this happens, but the implementation of *what* happens is entirely within the terminal.  Indeed, the TUI programs don't even have the same model of what is happening.  To them, they are switching into and out of "cursor addressing mode".

Not all terminals and terminal emulator programs even have an alternate screen buffer.  For example: the terminal emulator programs built into Linux and BSD kernels that provide their kernel virtual terminals usually don't have this capability.

On such terminals, there is no control sequence.  The termcap/terminfo database record for the terminal type will, consequently, not have such control sequence; and switching to and from "cursor addressing mode" overwrites the current screen content *without* saving and restoring it.

vim, nano, and whatnot *have no knowledge of this*.  They aren't doing anything different.  They aren't what performs the function.  They are simply emitting the control sequences that termcap/terminfo tell them will enter and exit "cursor addressing mode".  For some terminals, that have the mechanism, "cursor addressing mode" also means *use the alternate screen buffer*.  For some, that have not, it does not.

### Further reading

- https://superuser.com/a/715563/38062