# Restoring the session after running a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

From a bash script that occupies the full terminal, how do I restore the previous session?

A few programs of which I know they work this way:

- ranger
- vim
- man
- nano

The common pattern is: The program usurps the whole terminal, and then, upon exiting, everything is restored, i.e. entered commands and printed output.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to save/restore terminal output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243237/how-to-save-restore-terminal-output)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but is some (possibly useful) additional knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the terminfo `cup` options.  This can be done from a shell with the `tput` command.

eg

```
tput smcup
clear
echo hello
echo there
read
tput rmcup
```

This will clear the screen, print two lines, wait for you to press RETURN and then restore the screen to where it was before.

This requires the `terminfo` definition for your terminal to support this, of course.  Not all terminals have the capability.

Comment: Works. Already figured out that googling for 'bash alternate screen' gives me the desired behaviour, while I tried 'bash restore session'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `clear` or `tput clear` messes up the history of the original screen when used in a bash script. The screen is still there but only the visible screen. All the history is gone.
It took me ages to find out that `clear` has to be replaced with `tput cup 0 0` (works in my case by positioning the cursor upper left).

```
tput smcup
tput cup 0 0  # position cursor top left, simulate clear
...script
tput rmcup
```